# Rewriting URLs that work from subfolder and root

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I building a site that has SEO friendly URLs, the URLs on the live site look something like: http://www.somesite.com/seo/friendly/url

I also have a staging server that I am using to test the site. On this server the URLs look something like this : http://127.0.0.1**/~somesite**/seo/friendly/url

Now, SEO urls work on the live site but fail on the test as the substitution in .htaccess captures the /~somesite substring as a variable as well.

How can I begin substitution from where my index.php lives?

Here is the substitution code I am using now:

```
RewriteRule ^(([\w\-\/])+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, since it will be impossible to distinguish the directory path from the rest of the url fragments. The easiest thing would be to deploy the `.htaccess` in each sites root directory instead of the actual web root. In this case your previous `RewriteRule` should be sufficient.

```
RewriteRule ^([\w\-\/]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If you then had the following directory structures and used the following urls `http://example.com/~mysite/seo/friendly/url` and `http://example.com/sample/test/seo/friendly/url` they would both produce the same result `index.php?page=seo/friendly/url`.

```
~mysite/
  .htaccess
  index.php

sample/
  test/
    .htaccess
    index.php
```

Comment: not sure... this tilde will be placed with full uri as a page uri... I think author need exclude it somehow from the parameter value like `RewriteRule ^((~mysite)\/([\w\-\/])+)$ index.php?page=$2 [L,QSA]` ?

Comment: Tilde cannot be used as an identifier in this specific case as the application is going to be deployed on multiple servers which I do not know their exact deployment path nor can I create specific .htaccess files for each one. Is there a way to identify the base path where index.php is launched from? I would guess its the same path .htaccess is at as well.

Comment: @paishin - The easiest way would be to store your `.htaccess` in the root of your site ie `~mysite/.htaccess` and not in the actual webroot. If the directory structure is at most one level deep you could do `RewriteRule ^(~[\w\-]?)([\w\-\/]+)$ ~$1/index.php?page=$2 [L,QSA]`

Comment: @Cyclone, I followed your suggestion but unfortunately it doesn't work. RewriteRule picks up the same url regardless where it is stored.

Also `RewriteRule ^(~[\w\-]?)([\w\-\/]+)$ ~$1/index.php?page=$2 [L,QSA]` cannot distinguish parts of the url that are path from those that are seo aliases for example `http://example.com/root/alias` from `http://example.com/alias/sub-alias`

Comment: @paishin - Seems really strange? This works perfectly for me. Perhaps the `.htaccess` is cached somehow? Try empty you browsers cache and notice that I edited the rule above.

Comment: @paishin - Then my quess would be that there are some other `.htaccess` perhaps in the root, that will override the rules.

Comment: @Cyclone I found out there is an enviromental variable called {SCRIPT_NAME} that gets the path to the index.php like ~subdirectory/index.php. Can we somehow concatenate the '/index.php' and add the '~subdirectory' part in the rewrite rule?

Comment: @paishin - If you give me your email and can send you a `.tar` with a working example.